# Reconstituting Long File Names (LFN) from 8.3 on NAS server after system crash

Tags: filesystems, fat32

My FAT32 NAS has lost its long filenames in several different directories.

It only shows 8.3 filenames.

How might I get the LFNs back?

This happened in the midst of a main system crash that required reformatting and reconstituting the hard disk from backups. I have not touched the NAS, so can only wonder why I can no longer see LFNs, only 8.3.

Summary:

```
1. NAS description

2. Problem

3. Actions subsequent to crash (none to the NAS)

4. File types: root—btrfs, data—XFS, formerly Ext4

5. PATH_MAX and NAME_MAX appear alright

6. convnv encoding is the same for 8.3 and LFN?

7. Numerous examinations of **man mount**

8. Parent app for files: Evolution email client
```

I am still clueless at this point despite hours of deliberate investigation detailed below. I've learned a lot about file systems and file names in the process, but not a solution. I shall appreciate any possible help.

Best regards, Andy

=====

1. The unit is

   Western Digital (WD) "My Book" Essential 2TB NAS
2. The main hassle is with thousands of local email folders and messages for the Linux Gnome Evolution email client. I have a separate older backup on a WD FAT32 USB SSD (Solid State Drive) that preserves LFNs for the folders, but the messages are much older there. An attempt to copy the newer backup (8.3) files simply ignores the older LFN files and saves as 8.3, duplicating the content.
3. **I have not saved** any files to either the SSD or NAS since the crash so cannot imagine that their contents have actually been changed, rather suspect that *my new configuration is not reading them correctly.*
4. We reformatted the root partition (/) as **btrfs** and the data partition **XFS**, per the recommendations of the operating system (**openSUSE Leap 42.1**) in the course of  reconstitution. The data partition is **LUKS encrypted**. The root and data partitions originally were **Ext4**. *Hopefully LFN should not depend on Ext4?*
5. Path and File name limitations are 4096/255 respectively on both the main system and the NAS:

{serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux}

```
# getconf NAME_MAX /dev/sda3 
255
# getconf PATH_MAX /dev/sda3 
4096
```

HOWEVER

{kb.netapp.com/support/index?page=content&id=3011981&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1452757427425}

says that the path length is *included* in the **NAME_MAX** limit, which would certainly explain the problem. But this was not a problem before the crash, so I wonder why it is now?

OTOH

{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems} (yes I know not a proper technical reference but useful anyhow >:-)

repeats the getconf **NAME_MAX** limit above, and says that for **btrfs** and **XLS** file systems there is no **PATH_MAX** limit.

Again, these problems did not exist before the crash, the parameters are the same, so I have trouble understanding that the file system change is the culprit.

6. I've learned about **convmv** {www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/}. It sounds promising, but apparently useless as it seems that 8.3 and LFN are both UTF8 file names. I have not found any place that gives explicit encoding for these two name formats.
7. I see that I should consider **mount** options, but ***which?***

The mount command I am using is

**mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.5.1/"My Book" /mnt/NAS**

This worked fine before all this happened. As we know the options for **mount** are as countable as the stars... :-(

As I understand matters, this mounts the drive as an NFS drive. Seeing 8.3 file names contradicts the *kb.netapp.com* citation above, which says:

*The short names appear on clients that support only the 8.3 format. The short names are not visible to NFS clients.*

These indeed appear to be NFS clients, so should *not* see the 8.3. Very odd.

So we examine **mount** in detail:

{linux.die.net/man/8/mount}

Some areas for investigation; none of these were used before, we can work through them as explicit options to see if they remove the problem:

```
cifs:

See the options section of the mount.cifs(8) man page 
 (cifs-utils package must be installed).
```

It ***is*** installed.

{linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs}

```
mount.cifs {service} {mount-point} [-o options]
mount.cifs //192.168.5.1/"My Book" /mnt/NAS -o guest,uid=1000,gid=100,rw
```

This is run by root and mounts the NAS as chown **andy:users** but the files still appear as 8.3.

Try the FAT **check=r** option:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.5.1/"My Book" /mnt/NAS -o guest,uid=1000,gid=100,rw,check=r
```

but that is not allowed.

```
fat:

    check=r
```

It looks like check=s is in effect, disallowing LFNs. Has this become a default setting?

```
codepage=value

Sets  the codepage for converting to shortname characters on FAT
and VFAT filesystems. By default, codepage 437 is used.

iocharset=value

Character set to use for converting between 8 bit characters and
16 bit Unicode characters. The default is iso8859-1.  Long file-
names are stored on disk in Unicode format.
```

So we try:

```
mount -t fat -o guest //192.168.5.1/"My Book" /mnt/NAS
```

but no joy.

```
vfat:

First of all, the mount options for fat are recognized. 
The dotsOK option is explicitly killed by vfat. Furthermore, there are
```

nothing that looks particularly helpful, and

```
mount -t vfat -o guest //192.168.5.1/"My Book" /mnt/NAS
```

fails.

8. The parent application for the majority of 8.3 files is the Gnome Evolution email client. But again, these are backup files, not the actual data files that were lost in the crash. So it continues to evade me how the the original LFNs mysteriously became 8.3 without any direct action on my part. So it must be a **mount** or *file system properties* issue.

Thanks again, Andy

Comment: What was the original system configuration where the file system backups were made from? How did you exactly make the backups? What is the filesystem of the backup device?

Comment: The system was essentially the same  except Ext4, not btfrs +XLS. The backup system is FAT32 I make the backups using rsync in a script:

rsync $excludes -Dvurtl $sourcepath$filename $destpath2

where 

 excludes="--exclude=*.vdi --exclude=*.vmdk --exclude=*.dpi --exclude=*.iso"

. This has all worked before the crash, just not after.

Comment: So you had tried restoring before and it worked fine?

Comment: I am suspecting here that the unit somehow has failed to store the filenames correctly. There aren't any filenames lost in mounting, no kernel parameters affect filesystem filename lengths. Btrfs, XFS, Ext4 etc. all support long filenames, as that is a basic requirement for a Unix filesystem. It is actually quite weird that the unit would use FAT32 as its filesystem, since that is a bad choice in so many ways.

Comment: Tero hello. We don't know what we don't know... :-( Thank you for eliminating things about which I was wondering. Indeed, we need to talk to Western Digital, as they have chosen FAT for their file system.

At the end of the day, we have spent a hideous amount of time on this, so I've just sucked it up and gone on with my life, reconstructing the directories as necessary. None of it will matter in another few years anyhow. Had there been a way to recover it then fine, but it's not worth heart and panic attacks.
Kind regards, Andy